# swift: loop through all cells in a uitableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm new to swift and xcode,
I have a table view cell with a string var.
I want to be able to go over all my cells and put all the strings in a nice array of string.

what function should I use to loop through the strings?

I want to do it when a uibutton is tapped with an action function like this:

```
@IBAction func addToCheckTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) { 
// go over all the cells and append all the strings to my array.
}
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html

Comment: The strings should already be in an array (or some model object). Don't abuse the cells as the data source.

Comment: the tableview lazy loads its cells so it only has cells for the data that is on screen or prefetched.  There is no way you can get all of the cell contents unless all of the cells are visible.  You are supposed to maintain some kind of data source for the cells, usually and array or database query and you should get your strings from there.  The cells get there data from the datasource and not vice versa; it should be a unidirectional dataflow.

Comment: The thing is I use radio button and in my tableview I want to check which ones are checked.
I have a action in my cell that update the string every time a radiobutton is checked.

Comment: @H.Epstein: That makes no difference. The state of the radio buttons should be stored in a data source, e.g. in an array. – Don't forget that cells are *reused,* i.e. a cell displaying row X can later be used to display row Y.